# Error trying to average the elements of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, average, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I want to calculate the average of elements from a linked list:

.h

```
class List
{
public:
    List() { head = NULL; }
    void insertNode(int);//inserare nod la sfarsitul unei liste
    void printList();//afisare lista
    void deleteNode(int);
    void medie(float);
```

.cpp

```
void List::medie(float) {
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int media = 0;
    Node* temp3 = head;
    while (temp3 != NULL) {
        count++;
        sum += temp3->val;
        temp3 = temp3->next;
    }
    media = (double)sum / count;
    return media;
}
```

I received this error:

> return value type doesn't match the function type

I don't know how to repair it.

Comment: You declared a function with no return value, so what are you trying to do with `return media;`?

Comment: I am guessing that you have not yet learned that the many `void`s you have in this code are all _return types_.  You are promising a `void` return type and then attempting to instead return an `int`.

Comment: @my_name Also the function parameter is not used. Why is it present?

Comment: Also this code delivers _many errors_.  What's `head`?  What's `Node`?  What's `val`? This is not a [mre].

Comment: Regardless of whether you want to practice with self-built datatypes or are looking for a solution for a real-world application: Don't roll your own containers, use standard ones -- and then learn all there is to learn about `<algorithm>`... -- Also, sooner or later your code *will* be read by someone from a different country. English is the way to go with identifiers and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is declared with the return type `void`

```
void medie(float);
```

So it means that it returns nothing. However within the function definition there is a return statement with a non-void expression.

```
return media;
```

So the compiler issues an error message.

Also the function parameter is not used within the function. Its declaration does not make a sense.

In this statement

```
media = (double)sum / count;
```

there is no great sense to cast the variable `sum` to the type `double` because the result is assigned to the variable `media` having the type `int`.

The function should be declared the following way

```
double medie() const;
```

and defined like

```
double List::medie() const
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( const Node *temp = head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next )
    {
        sum += temp->val; 
        ++count;
    }

    return count == 0 ? 0.0 : sum / count;
}
```